# Why am I not able to translate Y position of a pattern in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, html, svg

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/9vpv1ema/1/):

```
<div id="linkz" style="cursor:pointer;">Move pattern</div>

<div id="container">
    <div id="gray">
        <svg>
            <defs>
                <pattern id="bg" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="640" height="319" >
                    <image xlink:href="http://cdn2.stbm.it/zingarate/gallery/foto/le-spettacolari-foto-dal-mondo-da-usare-come-immagine-di-copertina-di-facebook/maldive_2.jpeg" width="640" height="319" />
                </pattern>             
            </defs>

            <text class="my-text" id="text-1" x="20px" y="20" fill="url(#bg)" dominant-baseline="hanging">Item 1</text>      
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>

$('#linkz').click(function() {
    $('#bg').attr('y', 30);
});
```

when I click on "Move pattern" it should translate the `y` coordinate of the pattern of 20px. It works fine in Firefox, but I'm not able to do this in Chrome (last version). Where am I wrong?

Comment: Yh this works on chrome 44.0.2403.157 m but not on 45.0.2454.85 m

Comment: @Popnoodles Does work in Chrome 47.0.2498.0 dev-m though.

Comment: Ok it may be a bug in that version

Comment: Ah so? When can I show the bugfixes? :(

Comment: I'd suggest filing a bugreport at http://crbug.com.